# sed regex matching not working

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to update the year in licence header of the source code in many files.
I am writing bash sript for that. However the **sed** command is not working. In particular, the regex fails to match and replace the desired word.

Example: mycode.h

```
<Some Multi Line text>
Copyright 2002-2014 Utkrist Adhikari
<Some Multi Line text>
```

Lets say I want to replace 2014 by 2015 (***END_DATE=2015***). I am trying to achieve it with following command:

```
sed -i -r "s/\(Copyright.*\)-[ ]*[0-9]+[ ]*\( Utkrist Adhikari\)/\1$END_DATE\2/" mycode.h
```

OR

```
sed '/Copyright/,/Peter Baumann/ {s/-[ ]*[0-9]+[ ]*/$END_DATE/}' $file
```

Basically, I am trying to match

- ***Copyright*** at the beginning of the line;
- ***-[optional_spaces]some_integer[optional_spaces]*** in between
- ***[one_space]Utkrist Adhikari*** at the end of the line

I would then like to replace the middle part with content of the variable **END_DATE**

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below GNU sed command,

```
$ END_DATE=2015; sed -r "s/^(Copyright\s*[0-9]{4}-)[0-9]{4}(\s*Utkrist\s*Adhikari)/\1$END_DATE\2/g" file
<Some Multi Line text>
Copyright 2002-2015 Utkrist Adhikari
<Some Multi Line text>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r "s/^(Copyright 2002-)[0-9]{4}( Utkrist Adhikari)$/\1$END_DATE\2/" mycode.h
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it with `awk`

```
awk '/Copyright/ {sub(/-[0-9]*/,"-2015")}1' file
<Some Multi Line text>
Copyright 2002-2015 Utkrist Adhikari
<Some Multi Line text>
```

When data comes from a variable:

```
END_DATE=2015
awk -v d="$END_DATE" '/Copyright/ {sub(/-[0-9]*/,"-"d)}1' file
<Some Multi Line text>
Copyright 2002-2015 Utkrist Adhikari
<Some Multi Line text>
```